# How I can add placeholder in shortcode

Tags: shortcode

```
  add_shortcode( 'show-the-views', function( ) {
    );
    $count = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'views', true );
    return $count . ' views';
});
```

This code is working but I have to add a placeholder in the shortcode for example [doc_wp_live_search placeholder="Have a question?"].
Currently, it is showing views. But I want to give an option for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function show_the_views_func( $atts ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'placeholder' => '',
        ), $atts 
    );

    $count = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'views', true );

    return $count . $atts['placeholder'] . ' views';
}
add_shortcode( 'show-the-views', 'show_the_views_func' );
echo do_shortcode( '[show-the-views placeholder="test"]' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works. But there is a slight change in the code. @Milan

Comment: can we add a dash icon in it

Comment: Yes you can add everything using attributes.Please refer this document https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/